# Check if application running - InstallJammer

Tags: installation, tcl, uninstallation

I am using InstallJammer for setup creation of my application. I want to check if the application is running before proceeding with uninstall procedure.

```
set program <%Company%><%AppName%>.exe
set pids [twapi::get_process_ids -name $program]
foreach pid $pids {
    catch {twapi::end_process $pid -force}
}
```

Above given is the TCL script I tried. But the script does not return any values. How to solve this.?

Comment: This script tries to kill any running application which happens to have a matching name; strictly speaking, it does not *check* anything, so there's nothing to return.  I would say this should be clear from the invocation of something called "end_process"...

Comment: On the other hand, it's not clear what you mean by "returning a value" -- how is your caller code supposed to get access to that value? A reference to the relevant bit of that "InstallJammer" documentation could help understand the requirements.

Comment: @kostix Is there any way to check if application is running? On searching this question, I got the above script as solution.    

http://installjammer.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=2261

Comment: `twapi::get_process_ids -name $program` returns a list of PIDs of the running processes which name matches `$program`. If the list is non-empty, you have your application running.  That is, `expr {[llength [twapi::get_process_ids -name $program]] > 0}` returns true only if you have at least one matching process currently running.

Comment: Would it close the installation program? That would be awesome! But unwanted…

Comment: @kostix can you provide the entire script as answer, if it is working? Am not so familiar with TCL scripting.

Comment: @Gapchoos, I can't as I do not even know what that "installJammer" thing really is. Well, I have a vague idea that this is supposedly a tool to prepare installable packages but that's all. Since I don't know how *it* is supposed to interact with the Tcl scripts it executes, I can't provide a full script. The snipped I posted in my previous comment should return true or false depending on whether the indicated program is found running or not. You could try to work from there.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you are using the [execute script condition](http://installjammer.com/docs/index.html?ExecuteScriptCondition), while it might be easier to just use the [script condition](http://installjammer.com/docs/index.html?ScriptCondition)

If you use the script condition, just use the expr given by kostix:

```
[llength [twapi::get_process_ids -name <%Company%><%AppName%>.exe]] > 0
```

If you really have to use the execute script condition, then just wrap everyting in `expr {` and `}` and you get the same result as the script condition (Or: a script condition is just a execute script condition with `expr {` at the beginning and `}` at the end).

```
expr {[llength [twapi::get_process_ids -name <%Company%><%AppName%>.exe]] > 0}
```